# Plot Bar Chart using Dojo

Tags: java, dojox.charting

How do I plot a bar chart using Dojo ? I have a database with 2 columns `empid` and `empsalary`. I want to plot a Bar Chart in dojo with `empid` as x-axis and `empsalary` as y-axis. Please suggest.

Thanks in advance
Rahul Kumar

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script to plot a bar chart with Dojo charting:

```
<script>
require([
    // Require the basic chart class
    "dojox/charting/Chart",

    // Require the theme of our choosing
    "dojox/charting/themes/MiamiNice",

    // Charting plugins:

    //  We want to plot Columns
    "dojox/charting/plot2d/Columns",

    //  We want to use Markers
    "dojox/charting/plot2d/Markers",

    //  We'll use default x/y axes
    "dojox/charting/axis2d/Default",

    // Wait until the DOM is ready
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function(Chart, theme) {

    // Define the data
    var chartData = [10000,9200,11811,12000,7662,13887,14200,12222,12000,10009,11288,12099];

    // Create the chart within it's "holding" node
    var chart = new Chart("chartNode");

    // Set the theme
    chart.setTheme(theme);

    // Add the only/default plot
    chart.addPlot("default", {
        type: "Columns",
        markers: true,
        gap: 5
    });

    // Add axes
    chart.addAxis("x");
    chart.addAxis("y", { vertical: true, fixLower: "major", fixUpper: "major" });

    // Add the series of data
    chart.addSeries("Monthly Sales",chartData);

    // Render the chart!
    chart.render();

});

</script>

<div id="chartNode" style="width:800px;height:400px;"></div>
```

Please find detailed explanation [here in Dojo tutorials](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/charting/)